# Running Counter in SQL 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, count, inventory

I'm trying to establish a temp table for a running inventory demand report in SQL 2008.  I can get the results that I am looking for until I hit an invoice with multiple lines.  Here is the code so far:

```
--Gather Current Order Data
DECLARE @b TABLE ([Planned Shipment Date] DATE, [Order] VARCHAR(15), [Line Number] VARCHAR(15), [Location] VARCHAR(15), [Item] VARCHAR(15), [QuantityUsed] INT)

INSERT INTO @b
SELECT [Planned Shipment Date], [Document No_], [Line No_], [Location Code], No_, CAST(SUM([Outstanding Quantity]) AS INT)
FROM [STAGE].[dbo].[TRU$Sales Line]
WHERE [Document No_] LIKE 'SO%'
AND [Gen_ Prod_ Posting Group] IN ('TOY', 'AUDIO', 'BICYCLE')
AND [Outstanding Quantity] <> 0
GROUP BY [Document No_], [Location Code], [Line No_], [Planned Shipment Date], No_
ORDER BY [Planned Shipment Date], [Document No_], [Line No_], [Location Code], No_

--Gather Current Inventory Data
DECLARE @a TABLE ([Item] VARCHAR(15), [Location] VARCHAR(15), [Inventory] INT)

INSERT INTO @a
SELECT [Item No_], [Location Code], CAST(SUM([Quantity]) AS INT)
FROM [STAGE].[dbo].[TRU$Item Ledger Entry]
GROUP BY [Item No_], [Location Code]
ORDER BY [Item No_], [Location Code]

DROP TABLE ##TEMP
--Insert to a temp table for testing
SELECT [Planned Shipment Date], [Location], [Item], [Order], [Line Number], 
[Outstanding Qty], [Total Inventory], [Running Order Total]
INTO ##TEMP
FROM
 (SELECT 
   [order].[Planned Shipment Date]
  ,[order].[Location] 
  ,[order].[Item] 
  ,[order].[Order]
  ,[order].[Line Number]
  ,0 AS [Outstanding Qty]
  ,(SELECT SUM(inventory)
    FROM @a inv
    WHERE inv.item = [order].[Item] 
    AND inv.location = [order].[Location]) AS [Total Inventory] 
  ,(SELECT SUM(QuantityUsed) 
    FROM @b prevorder 
    WHERE prevorder.item = [order].[Item] 
    AND prevorder.location = [order].[Location] 
    AND prevorder.[order] <= [order].[Order]
    ) AS [Running Order Total]
  FROM @b [order] 
 ) AS OrderExtended 
--WHERE [Total Inventory] < [Running Order Total]
ORDER BY [Planned Shipment Date], [Order], [Line Number], [Location], [Item] ASC
GO
--Display outstanding quantity to ship on the temp table
UPDATE ##TEMP
SET [Outstanding Qty] = SL.[Outstanding Quantity]
FROM ##TEMP T, [TRU$Sales Line] SL
WHERE T.[Order] = SL.[Document No_]
AND T.[Line Number] = SL.[Line No_]
GO
```

When I run a query such as:

```
SELECT * FROM ##TEMP
WHERE Item = '1011861'
ORDER BY [Order], [Line Number]
```

I get something like (incorrect running total of outstanding qty):

```
Planned Shipment Date | Location | Item | Order | Line Number | Outstanding Qty | Total Inventory | Running Order Total
2010-08-20              HQ       1011861  SO18727    6          3                 49                 103
2010-09-10              HQ       1011861  SO18727    7          50                49                 103
2010-10-01              HQ       1011861  SO18727    8          34                49                 103
2010-08-20              HQ       1011861  SO18731    6          45                49                 174
2010-09-10              HQ       1011861  SO18731    7          26                49                 174
2010-08-20              HQ       1011861  SO19268    1          1                 49                 175
2010-08-26              HQ       1011861  SO20476    8          1                 49                 176
2010-08-26              HQ       1011861  SO20552    4          1                 49                 177
2010-08-27              HQ       1011861  SO20630    8          2                 49                 179
```

What I am expecting is something like (a true running total of outstanding qty):

```
Planned Shipment Date | Location | Item | Order | Line Number | Outstanding Qty | Total Inventory | Running Order Total
2010-08-20              HQ       1011861  SO18727    6          3                 49                 3
2010-09-10              HQ       1011861  SO18727    7          50                49                 53
2010-10-01              HQ       1011861  SO18727    8          34                49                 87
2010-08-20              HQ       1011861  SO18731    6          45                49                 132
2010-09-10              HQ       1011861  SO18731    7          26                49                 158
2010-08-20              HQ       1011861  SO19268    1          1                 49                 159
2010-08-26              HQ       1011861  SO20476    8          1                 49                 160
2010-08-26              HQ       1011861  SO20552    4          1                 49                 161
2010-08-27              HQ       1011861  SO20630    8          2                 49                 163
```

It seems that when a different shipment date is included on an order (more than one line per order) it throws my query off.  What am I missing?  I have looked at this so much that I'm afraid that I can't see the obvious solution.

Thanks for any help,
Doug

Answer (score 0):

You have to limit [Line Number] when prevorder.Order=[order].Order:

```
(SELECT SUM(QuantityUsed) FROM @b prevorder        
 WHERE prevorder.item = [order].[Item] AND prevorder.location = [order].Location]        
 AND (prevorder.[order] < [order].[Order] OR (prevorder.[order] = [order].[Order]         
 AND prevorder.[Line Number] <= [order].[Line Number]))         
 AS [Running Order Total]
```

It would be more useful to order the report by [Planned Shipment Date], Order, [Line Number].

```
(SELECT SUM(QuantityUsed) FROM @b prevorder        
 WHERE prevorder.item = [order].[Item] AND prevorder.location = [order].Location]
 AND (prevorder.[Planned Shipment Date] < [order].[Planned Shipment Date] OR
 (prevorder.[Planned Shipment Date] = [order].[Planned Shipment Date]       
 AND (prevorder.[order] < [order].[Order] OR (prevorder.[order] = [order].[Order]         
 AND prevorder.[Line Number] <= [order].[Line Number])))         
 AS [Running Order Total]
```

Getting too Complex?  Use a table with an Identity Column = RecordID intead of the #temp table.  Insert the records in the order they should appear in the report.

```
(SELECT SUM(QuantityUsed) FROM @b prevorder        
 WHERE prevorder.Item = [order].[Item] AND prevorder.location = [order].Location]
 AND prevorder.RecordID <= [order].RecordID) AS [Running Order Total]
```